# Primefaces BlockUI

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

The below code works as expected when the component `"resultsScrollPanel"` is available.
It's not always the case and to safeguard, added the `c:if` condition. However, even when the value of `myBean.viewResults == false`, it fails stating component `"resultsScrollPanel"` cannot be found. The block attribute of `p:blockUI` cannot be empty either.

Any clues to resolve this issue and dynamically construct `p:blockUI`?

Thanks for your time and help.

```
<c:if test="${myBean.viewResults}">
<p:blockUI id="blockUI" widgetVar="bui" block="resultsScrollPanel" >
<p >When you have finished modifying
</p:blockUI>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the rendered attribute of the blockUI tag:

```
<p:blockUI id="blockUI" widgetVar="bui" block="resultsScrollPanel" rendered="#{myBean.viewResults}">
   <p>When you have finished modifying</p>
</p:blockUI>
```